# jQuery issues with the 'this' modifier and if/else statement

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, if-statement, this

Ok, so I'm trying to make it so that an image can be modified or moved in the browser by clicking on buttons on the side of the page, but the script in my if/else statement isn't working like I'd like it to. Here's what I have so far in jQuery:

```
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Image Mod</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/main.js">
var menu = $('ul li').click(function() {
console.log($(this).index());


if (menu = 0) {
$('this').css('width', '80%')
}

else if (menu = 1) {
$('this').css('height', '80%')  
}

else if (menu = 2) {
$('this').css('height', '80%')
}

else if (menu = 3) {
$('this').css('top', '30')
}

else if (menu = 4) {
$('this').css('left', '50')
}

else if (menu = 5) {
$('this').css('left', -50')
}
else {

}
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <nav id="sidebar">
        <ul>
            <li>Edit 1</li>
            <li>Edit 2</li>
            <li>Edit 3</li>
            <li>Edit 4</li>
            <li>Edit 5</li>
            <li>Edit 6</li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
    <img class="active" src="images/picture.jpg" />
</body>
```

Comment: are you aware of the fact that your `if...else` is  written  outside the event handler..?

Comment: Can you post the html?

Comment: Using `$('menu')` targets the `<menu>` tag (which is deprecated in HTML 4.01). If you want to use your variable, just use `menu` (although I'm not sure storing an event handler in a variable is useful but I might be wrong on that one).

Comment: Also, you're doing an affectation (`=`) in your *if* statements when you want to go for a comparison (`==`).

Comment: @td-edge no problem, added

Comment: @D4V1D i tried that...no luck. Should I use .index to move the image instead of .css?

Comment: @Ultra You are not referring to the current object instance $(this). Also, you should use a switch() statement instead of all that concatenation of ifs.

Answer (score 1):

$('this') is a selector for a <this> tag.

Change it to $(this)

In your if statements, a single = is an assignment and it will evaluate to true if the value on the right is non-zero.  You need to use == to test for equality.  You should consider a switch statement, like so:

```
switch ($(this).index())  {
    case 0: // Stuff
          break;
    case 1: // More stuff
          break;
    default:
          // No other match
}
```

Comment: It's better to check index value: `$(this).index();`

Comment: @optic That's what I originally tried, but I had trouble with it...how would you suggest I do it?

Comment: Change **switch (menu)** to switch **($(this).index())** - Thank you @optic

Answer (score 0):

Basically, you are wrong in

- doing your *if/else* statement outside the event handler
- doing affectation instead of comparison
- checking for the return value of the handler when you want to check for `$('li').index();`

---

So for this given HTML:

```
<nav id="sidebar">
     <ul>
         <li>Edit 1</li>
         <li>Edit 2</li>
         <li>Edit 3</li>
         <li>Edit 4</li>
         <li>Edit 5</li>
         <li>Edit 6</li>
     </ul>
</nav>
<section>
    <img class="active" src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/" />
</section>
```

<sup>`<section>` is needed because you want to change the `<img>` height</sup>

And this given CSS:

```
#sidebar li {cursor: pointer;}
#sidebar li:hover {color: purple;}
section {height: 200px;}
img {height: 100%; position: relative;}
```

You would need to use this jQuery code:

```
jQuery(function($) {

    $('#sidebar').find('li').on('click', function() {
        var position = $(this).index(), // the position of the <li> in the <ul>
            css = {
                property: null,
                value: null
            }, // prepare to store CSS properties and values to apply to the img
            $img = $('img'); // the img on which CSS changes are applied

        // define CSS properties and values according to the position of the <li> clicked
        switch(position) {
            case 0:
                css.property = 'width';
                css.value = '80%';
                break;
            case 1:
                css.property = 'height';
                css.value = '80%';
                break;
            case 2:
                css.property = 'height';
                css.value = '80%';
                break;
            case 3:
                css.property = 'top';
                css.value = '30px';
                break;
            case 4:
                css.property = 'left';
                css.value = '50px';
                break;
            case 5:
                css.property = 'left';
                css.value = '-50px';
                break;
        }

        // apply CSS properties
        $img.css(css.property, css.value);

    });

});
```

[Working JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/n5zjq4vq/)